# Masking First and Last Name String with *

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a string that is combination of first and lastname:

> Johnny Tuck

I want to mask that string like that in Swift 3:

> J***** T***

How can I do this ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: What if there is a middle name (which may be abbreviated or not)? What about foreign language names such as chinese?

Comment: @shallowThought it's hard to show something if you don't know where to start. @ mTuran this is a cool question :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could e.g. use pattern matching for lower-case characters and replace those that match the pattern with asterisk characters (`*`):

```
let name = "Johnny Tuck"
let pattern = Character("a")..."z"
let maskedName = String(name.characters.map { pattern ~= $0 ? Character("*") : $0 })
print(maskedName) // J***** T***
```

If the purpose is not to replace lower case characters by `*` but rather to mask all characters that are not the first of a given word (for, say, a specific separator `" "`), you could separate the `String` name by a separator, and apply a masking to all but the initial character for all separated words (sub-names), follwed by finally reconstruct the masked string:

```
import Foundation
let name = "johnny  lucky tuck"
let maskedName = name.components(separatedBy: " ")
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty }.map { $0.characters }
    .map { String($0.first!).uppercased() + String(repeating: "*", count: $0.dropFirst(1).count) }
    .joined(separator: " ")
print(maskedName) // J***** L**** T***
```

Note the `uppercased()` above, which sets the initial non-masked letter to a uppercased one (even if it is not initially). If you do not wish this uppercasing, simply remove the `.uppercased()` call above.

Comment: If the first character is small letter it won't work right, right?

Comment: Another way would be to split the string up, uppercase the first letter, then star them out.. you can do this with the built in methods of `String` @AhmadF `NSString` and `Character` (formerly NSCharacter) also have extended string methods

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution:

(split to words, filter out empty words, index every character in word, map to stars, join into full name again)

```
let fullname = "This Is My Name"

let result = fullname
    .components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
    .map { (name: String) in
        let mappedCharacters = name.characters.enumerated().map { (index, letter) in
            return (index == 0) ? letter : "*"
        }

        return String(mappedCharacters)
    }
    .joined(separator: " ")

print("Result:", result) // Result: T*** I* M* N***
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to replace each character except the first in each word by a star, then this would
be another possible solution:

```
extension String {
    /// Replace all characters except the first by a star.
    func starredWord() -> String {
        return String(characters.prefix(1) + characters.dropFirst().map { _ in "*" })
    }

    /// Star every "word" in a string.
    func starred() -> String {
        var result = ""
        self.enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..<endIndex, options: .byWords) { 
            (s, range, enclosingRange, _) in
            result +=
                // Append the substring preceeding the word ...
                self[enclosingRange.lowerBound..<range.lowerBound]
                // ... the starred word ...
                + (s?.starredWord() ?? "")
                // ... and the substring following the word.
                + self[range.upperBound..<enclosingRange.upperBound]
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Here `enumerateSubstrings` is used with the `.byWords` option to
detect words in the current locale, even if they are delimited by
punctuation characters.

Example:

```
let name = "John M. Doe, sen."
print(name.starred())
// J*** M. D**, s**.
```