# How to mask a String to show only the last 3 characters?

Tags: swift, string, masking

I just tried to mask String as below, but I didn't find what I want after do some search and research.

string a = "0123456789"
masked = "xxxxxxx789"

I modified solutions in this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224637/masking-first-and-last-name-string-with but it just change the String that doesn't match with the pattern. I have no idea how to change the pattern to match with what I mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does String substring work in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift-3)

Comment: Have a look here, how to get a substring of a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677330/how-does-string-substring-work-in-swift-3 Now you could "fill up" the rest of the total length of the input string with "x"

Comment: Thankyou, I use "string.replaceRange" and the code works fine as I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does exactly what you want:

```
let name = "0123456789"
let conditionIndex = name.characters.count - 3
let maskedName = String(name.characters.enumerated().map { (index, element) -> Character in
    return index < conditionIndex ? "x" : element
})
print("Masked Name: ", maskedName) // xxxxxxx789
```

What happens here is that you get an array of the characters of the string using `enumerated()` method, then map each character to a value based on a condition:

- If the index of the character is less than `condtionIndex` we replace the character with an `x` (the mask).
- Else, we just leave the character as is.

Comment: Thankyou, I am new to Swift, it seems that your code more simple than my code above, and both of them are the correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

You can get the last 3 characters of your string using the collection method `suffix(_ maxLength: Int)` and fill the other part of the string repeating the "x":

---

edit/update

**Swift 4 or later**

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var masked: String {
        return String(repeating: "•", count: Swift.max(0, count-3)) + suffix(3)
    }
}
```

---

```
let string = "0123456789"
print(string.masked)   // "•••••••789\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

who want this in obj C, can use this

```
    NSString *phone = @"0123456789";

    NSString *lastChr = [phone substringFromIndex: [phone length] - 3];

    NSMutableString *mask = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

    for (int i=0; i<[phone length]-3; i++) {
        [mask appendString:@"*"];

    }
    [mask appendString:lastChr];
```

Comment: That is Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: The question is *tagged* with [swift].

Answer (score 1):

I use this, very simple:

```
var pan: String?
var maskedPan: String { return pan.enumerated().map({ return ($0 < 6 || $0 > 11) ? String($1) : "*" }).joined()}
```

where $0 is index and $1 is iterated character